# Modify Multiple Facts

Tags: jess

How can I decrement y for all my facts (points)?

I am doing it like this:

```
(defrule decrementY 
        ?pto<-(point (y ?py))       
        (test (< ?py 3))
        =>  
        (modify ?pto (y (+ 1 ?py))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically correct, but a no-loop is advisable.

```
(defrule decrementY 
    (declare (no-loop TRUE))
    ?pto<-(point (y ?py &: (< ?py 3) ))       
 =>  
    (modify ?pto (y (+ 1 ?py))))
```

If you really mean **de**crement, use

```
    (modify ?pto (y (- ?py 1))))
```